# Cannot open file with squid proxy

Tags: squid

Run Nikto tools to check PC.

```
- Nikto v2.1.6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Target IP:          10.xx.xx.xx
+ Target Hostname:    10.xx.xx.xx
+ Target Port:        8028
+ Start Time:         2017-04-25 04:46:05 (GMT-4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Server: squid/4.0.17
+ Retrieved via header: 1.1 localhost.localdomain (squid/4.0.17)
+ The anti-clickjacking X-Frame-Options header is not present.
+ The X-XSS-Protection header is not defined. This header can hint to the user agent to protect against some forms of XSS
+ Uncommon header 'x-cache-lookup' found, with contents: NONE from localhost.localdomain:8028
+ Uncommon header 'x-cache' found, with contents: MISS from localhost.localdomain
+ Uncommon header 'x-squid-error' found, with contents: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
+ The X-Content-Type-Options header is not set. This could allow the user agent to render the content of the site in a different fashion to the MIME type
+ No CGI Directories found (use '-C all' to force check all possible dirs)
+ Entry '<li><p>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not ed.</p></li>' in robots.txt returned a non-forbidden or redirect HTTP code (400)
+ "robots.txt" contains 1 entry which should be manually viewed.
```

Find squide 4.0.17 on port 8028 and it find robots.txt file

**But if I try open it in url receive an error:**
http://10.xx.xx.xx:8028/robots.txt

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

**How I can saw this file?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use nikto with proxy parameter. For example nikto -h http://example.com/ -useproxy 10.xx.xx.xx:8128. 
In this way it will scan using the proxy in use and it will find robots.txt. Also you can set proxy address in your browser and then you can open it in url. set proxy address in firefox browser ; preferences ->Advanced -> Network -> settings -> Manual proxy configuration